# collection_singular_ids in case of a has_many trough with source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I just have found a strange behavior of Active Record, where I am not sure if I am the problem or Active Record ;-).

I am using: Rails 4, Ruby 2.0

Here the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversation_participants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conversations, through: :conversation_participants
end

class ConversationParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversation_participants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participants, through: :conversation_participants, source: :user
end
```

Pretty straight forward besides the `has_many :participants`, which refers to user over `source:`.

Normally, it is possible to call collection_singular_ids on an has_many associated object. Like in this case:

```
User.find(1).conversation_ids
```

This works perfectly, I get back an array of conversations ids. But from the other side:

```
Conversation.find(1).participant_ids
```

I alway getting back `nil`. When I go back to the standard for the has_many:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversation_participants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :conversation_participants
end

Conversation.find(1).user_ids
```

will work fine.

When I look into the resulting queries, I see what the reason could be:

has_many :users creates:

```
SELECT "users".id FROM "users" INNER JOIN "conversation_participants" ON "users"."id" = "conversation_participants"."user_id" WHERE "conversation_participants"."conversation_id" = $1  [["conversation_id", 29]]
```

has_many :participants creates:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "conversation_participants" ON "users"."id" = "conversation_participants"."user_id" WHERE "conversation_participants"."conversation_id" = $1  [["conversation_id", 29]]
```

in the participants case I get a `SELECT "users".*` instead `SELECT "users".id`

(using `class_name: "User"` has also not helped)

Bug or human error?